# passwords changing on export/import of database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have a linux shared hosting with phpmyadmin and MySQL

I run a wamp server without any amends. MOstly it works fine.

However when I export out a database from the wamp and then export it into the Linux the passwords change and I have to go in and reset them.

What's going on please?

```
    --
-- Table structure for table `pfd8x_users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pfd8x_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `block` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sendEmail` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `registerDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `lastvisitDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `activation` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `params` text NOT NULL,
  `lastResetTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Date of last password reset',
  `resetCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Count of password resets since lastResetTime',
  `otpKey` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Two factor authentication encrypted keys',
  `otep` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'One time emergency passwords',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_name` (`name`),
  KEY `idx_block` (`block`),
  KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=401 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `pfd8x_users`
--

INSERT INTO `pfd8x_users` (`id`, `name`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `block`, `sendEmail`, `registerDate`, `lastvisitDate`, `activation`, `params`, `lastResetTime`, `resetCount`, `otpKey`, `otep`) VALUES
(400, 'Super User', 'NAME', 'fred@email.com', '$P$D5YNEQ62cnGZy0cFTL/x49uBSkdWU80', 0, 1, '2014-04-01 14:59:48', '2014-05-01 16:49:46', '0', '{"admin_style":"","admin_language":"","language":"","editor":"","helpsite":"","timezone":""}', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, '', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you post the sql that you are importing?

Comment: all of it? there's pages... which bit would you want to see please?

Comment: If it is the password bit that is the problem then please edit your answer to include the sql for the user table creation and then the bit to populate that specific table.

Comment: How are you generating the passwords?

Comment: its generated within joomla backend? Does that help?